# Smart crop for drupal 8?

Tags: 8, media

I find intresting plugins, for smart image croping:

https://www.drupal.org/project/smartcrop
https://www.drupal.org/node/907984
https://www.drupal.org/project/imagefield_focus

But all of them for drupal 7

Is there a module for Drupal 8? What can I do to install this on Drupal 8?

Answer (score 0):

## [Image Widget Crop](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_widget_crop)

> Provides an interface for using the features of the [Crop API](https://www.drupal.org/project/crop). Module
> is still under heavy development.
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> Posted by [woprrr](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_widget_crop)

Comment: No, this is for manual croping, I need a module that can crop automatically, based on content of image

Comment: In the question, you didn't say exactly what you meant by _smart cropping_, nor that the module should automatically crop images.